# How to Move projects from private account to Organization account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to move my projects from another private account to my new organization,
projects move fine but I find the same moved project still on a private account.
a can't delete it because I don't know if it permanently deleted from organization also. now I need to know how to delete the projects that moved from my private account to the organization account.?

Comment: See [Projects Migration](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#migrating_projects_no_org)

Comment: Assuming by **private account** you mean identity (Gmail, Workspace, etc), remove that identity from the project's IAM.